# React Admin: How to show a list of ids in an edit form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I'm having some issues displaying an array in a select component in React Admin.

I have a document `wonCar` that has a `variantId` field which refers to another document's array `cars`.

The models are like this (simplified)

```
wonCar = {
  _id: 0,
  carId: 0,
  variantId: 1
}

car = {
  _id: 0,
  variants: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      title: "variant 1"
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      title: "variant 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to build a form where you can edit from a dropdown list the variant of the `wonCar`.

```
<ReferenceField label="Set Variants" source="carId" reference="cars">
  <TextField source="variants" />
</ReferenceField>
```

With this I managed to get this text displayed in my edit page (this is the best I could achieve):

```
[{"_id":"0","title":"variant 1"}]
```

I tried several components in the docs but I couldn't figure out a way to show this in a select list. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Hey, did you try out the `SelectInput` or `SelectArrayInput`..?

Comment: Have you used SelectArrayInput https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#selectarrayinput ?